# Why does Unix ask for password when I try to pull a file with permission 777 using scp?

Tags: networking, files, permissions, scp

Let us consider that I have a file `/home/base/alpha.txt` with permission 777 i.e. `-rwxrwxrwx` in `user@host`.
Now, from system `host1` as `user1` i.e. `user1@host1`, I try to pull the file mentioned above using the following command:

```
scp user@host:/home/base/alpha.txt .
```

As per file permissions 777, everyone has read-write-execute permission i.e. anyone should be able to read, write and execute the mentioned file. Why does Unix ask for the `user@host` password then?

Comment: Not everyone in the world, just every process on host. But you're on host1, you have to connect to host and ask some process on host to read it and copy it to you, which needs authentication. Also, you're not using Unix.

Answer (score 5):

The file permissions apply on the host. The file still needs to be made visible externally; you’re using SSH (*via* `scp`) to do so, and it’s SSH which is asking for your password. This happens before anything involving the target file at all; the SSH server authenticates the connecting user, and only after that’s completed (successfully) is `scp` involved on the target host and the target file accessed.

If you want passwordless SSH access, you can set up keys to do so.

Incidentally, since you’re logging in as `user` on `host`, the relevant permissions for `alpha.txt` are only those which apply to `user`. If `user` is the owner of `alpha.txt`, `alpha.txt` only needs to be readable by its owner.

Comment: I understand that it is SSH that asks for the password but I think that this line "the relevant permissions for alpha.txt are only those which apply to user" is wrong. Does not the LSB in 777 apply for everyone and MSB for the owner of the file?

Comment: The first triple applies to the owner, the middle triple to the group, and the last triple to everyone else; but you haven’t specified what `user`’s relationship to `alpha.txt` is, which is why I wrote that the relevant permissions are those which apply to `user` (not “owner”, the specific `user` you’re accessing the file as). If `user` is `alpha.txt`’s owner, then the owner permissions apply; if `user` is a member of `alpha.txt`’s owning group, then the group permissions apply; otherwise, the other permissions apply.

Comment: user is the owner of the file. I did not mention it due to the irrelevancy of relationship when the permission is set as 777

Comment: @daedalus_hamlet when the password is being requested, SSH hasn't even started to look at the file. Only after the user is authenticated will SSH look for the file and check permissions. So the permissions being 777 are absolutely irrelevant until your user is authenticated with SSH.

Comment: @muru your comment clarifies it. Thanks.